# Set custom validation on a column in Oracle apex

Tags: sql, oracle, date, validation, oracle-apex

I want to create custom validation on the column named :P8_HOME and :P8_AWAY. I have few tables which identify basketball games.
You are the admin and want to add new game for the future. If either team has already a game on the same day, in which you want to add a game, then the system shows an error message.

For example, when game date, Home and Away team are input and push "add button", then the system will see whether either team has a game on that day or not. If it has, then the system will show message and reject it.

How can I add the validation in processing?
Here is the list of variables:
P8_GAME_ID
P8_GAME_DATE
P8_HOME
P8_AWAY
P8_HOME_POINT
P8_AWAY_POINT

[image]

Comment: Hello aha. Validations are very common in apex. Not sure what kind of help you need. Right click the page item in the builder and pick "Create Validation". There are many examples on google and on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can create [page level validation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HTMDB/bldr_validate.htm#HTMDB04018) for this.

1. Create Validation, type "No Rows Returned" (i.e. if any rows are returned, then it will be treated as validation failure)
2. Put below "SQL Query" for validation check

> ```
>     SELECT * 
>     FROM <your_table_name> games
>     WHERE games.home = :P8_HOME
>     AND games.away = :P8_AWAY
>     /*if you are using different date format from application date format, then use TO_DATE to convert into date */
>     AND games.date = :P8_GAME_DATE 
>     /* For new rows consider all rows in DB, for existing rows, don't consider current row*/
>     AND (:P8_GAME_ID IS NULL
>       OR games.game_id != :P8_GAME_ID)
> ```

3. Add proper "Error Message" and "Server Side conditions"

Answer (score 0):

- Right click your mandatory page item and create validation
- Another one is create process and select plsql block and you can validate all validation like if else condition base and then through your error message for rasie_application_error method